Evaluate blinding using Fisher's exact test
In a clinical trial, there are 3 groups A, B & C, but only 2 interventions which participants are blinded to. Everyone in group A got active treatment, and everyone in group B & C got placebo. At the end of the trial, participants are asked about what intervention they got. This creates a 2x3 contingency table like this:
Guess     A: B: C:
Active:   a, b, c
Placebo:  d, e, f

I can run a 2x3 Fisher's exact test or this table.
Or I can create a 2x2 table where the B and C columns are summed up, and run a Fisher's exact test on this one instead. These 2 tables yield different results.
What is the correct approach if I want to know if there was a significant difference in participants' ability to guess their arm between the groups? What different hypotheses are answered by the 2 different tests?

Welcome to CV. I think this is also kind of the answer to your question, but what is the difference between B and C, and does it matter? Do you want to know whether people knew they were active vs. placebo, or A vs. B vs. C? (It sounds like your data can only tell you the former)

Thanks! The difference between B & C is that they also got another intervention in different ways, so for instance A got drug1 & placebo2, B got placebo1 & drug2, and C got double placebo. However, this question is only about whether they think they got drug1 or not.
I want to know whether there is a difference in the rate of how many could guess they were getting drug1, i.e., if the blinding was balanced or not with regards to drug1.

At the moment this suffers from confusion
The preliminary problem I see here is that there appears to be confusion in your statement of the problem and accompanying comments in relation to what was actually done in each of the groups and how they differ.  In the comments you say that Groups B and C were given different active drugs, but you previously describe them as having been given a placebo.  Similarly, you then refer to multiple different kinds of placebos in the comment (placebo, placebo1, placebo2).
In a controlled experiment, a placebo ought to be an inert intervention that cannot plausibly have any direct causal effect on the outcome.  It is also an intervention for which the patient (at least) is blinded, so they cannot tell that they received an inert intervention instead of a "treatment".  Since the goal of the placebo is to blind the patient to which group they are in, it is unusual to have multiple different kinds of "placebos" or to label a placebo differently for a different group.  If you are actually giving different groups different "placebos" then this creates a danger that it could confound the experiment.
I recommend you go back and clarify exactly what is being done to each group, what is the nature of any inert intervention that you put forward as a placebo replacement for the active treatments of interest, etc.  Once you have clarified this, you will know whether two groups are receiving the same intervention or not (if they are receiving the same intervention then they are really just one group and there is no need to label them as two) and you may then determine what your groups are for your statistical testing.

For a placebo to work it needs to mimic the active intervention in terms of side-effects. So therefore if you run a trial with 2 interventions you might need 2 different placebos/controls. This way you get the design I explained:
A: intervention1 & placebo2,
B: intervention2 & placebo1,
C: placebo1 & placebo2

If you want to know whether patients could "guess" that they got drug 1, then you should run a 2x2 contingency table of A vs. C. For the question of guessing drug2 vs. placebo, you should compare group B to C (again with Fisher exact). Now, should you use a multiple comparison correction? I would not, but ...
Now, for why your 2x3 and 2x2 results did not agree, it simply may be because of the power of the test: as you described, combining B & C will create a larger sample size, and hence a 2x2 result could be significant, while a 2x3 one would not be (maybe you could describe the nature of the different results?).
Comparing A to B, for asking about guessing placebo1 does not seem appropriate, because group B got a treatment; so they may well have seen some positive results, which they would (correctly!) attribute to a treatment (which they did receive!). And for that same reason, combining B&C does not seem appropriate. Now, you could combine A&B (both had a treatment) and compare against C (true placebo): that would have greater power, and combine the 2 treatment groups. Probably the best way to evaluate blinding?
